# Postgresql query for updating multiple columns in different tables during join

Tags: mysql, postgresql

We're working on migrating data from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

Sample table structure:

```
                     Table "public.model"
       Column       |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 model_id           | integer                     | not null
 last_purchase_time | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "model_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (model_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "items" CONSTRAINT "items_model_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES model(model_id)

                  Table "public.items"
    Column     |            Type             | Modifiers 
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 item_id       | integer                     | not null
 purchase_time | timestamp without time zone | 
 model_id      | integer                     | 
Indexes:
    "items_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (item_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "items_model_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES model(model_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "invoice" CONSTRAINT "invoice_item_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items(item_id)

                 Table "public.invoice"
    Column    |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 inovoice_id  | integer                     | not null
 invoice_time | timestamp without time zone | 
 item_id      | integer                     | 
Indexes:
    "invoice_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (inovoice_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "invoice_item_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items(item_id)
```

If we've to update columns of single table using join then we can use below query in postgresql.

```
update model
   set last_purchase_time = now()
from items
     join invoice
        on items.item_id = invoice.item_id
where model.model_id = items.model_id
  and invoice.item_id = 2002;
```

Below is an update query for updating multiple columns in all tables, which works fine in MySQL.

```
update model
       join items
          on model.model_id = items.model_id
       join invoice
          on items.item_id = invoice.item_id
set model.last_purchase_time = now(),
    items.purchase_time = now(),
    invoice.invoice_time = now()
where invoice.item_id = 2002;
```

Can someone suggest an equivalent PostgreSQL query for updating multiple columns in different tables using join?

Comment: No, PostgreSQL only allows a single table to be updated with a single query. However, you can use multiple [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) to do multiple DML queries at the same time. -- But why do you store your data redundantly? `model.last_purchase_time` is calculable & I see no benefit from being able to supply different timestamps for `invoice` & `items`.

Comment: @pozs The tables are more complex in my environment with each table having more than 20 columns, for example purpose alone I've simplified it and used same `timestamp` across tables, in real case the values will differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in PostgreSQL:

```
WITH upd1 AS
        (UPDATE invoice
         SET invoice_time = current_timestamp
         FROM items
            JOIN model
               ON model.model_id = items.model_id
         WHERE items.item_id = invoice.item_id
            AND invoice.item_id = 2002
         RETURNING model.model_id, items.item_id),
     upd2 AS
        (UPDATE items
         SET purchase_time = current_timestamp
         FROM upd1
         WHERE upd1.item_id = items.item_id)
UPDATE model
SET last_purchase_time = current_timestamp
FROM upd1
WHERE upd1.model_id = model.model_id;
```

The only downside is that `items` and `model` will be updated more often than necessary.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, I'll also try to break down the logic by updating one column at a time to avoid unnecessary updates wherever its possible.